# How to get syntax group name of a floating window

Tags: syntax-highlighting, font, popup

I would like to change the font from bold to normal in my floating windows in Vim 8.*

I have this script [here](https://gist.github.com/dman777/d94f642a09e2d5a2537759e3120e23c2) that gets the syntax group name of the item under cursor. However, this will not work for the floating window since the cursor can not go into the floating window.

[image]

Comment: Please indicate Vim or Neovim...they have very different popup implementations.

Comment: vim 8.*  at the moment

Comment: Where is the float from? Is it a plugin, or did you make it?

Comment: coc-nvim and coc-tsserver. note: event though nvim is in the name, it supports vim.